# React native post image to server Required request part 'file' is not present

Tags: react-native, post, postman, image-uploading, http-status-code-400

There is no problem with sending photos from Postman.

header is  ---> 'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

body is ----> form-data , {file : image..}

**Sending headers to x-www-form-urlencoded or multi-part/form-data does not work.**

**(HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request)**

Note that there is no image capacity limitation in the API.
Check out the screenshot for more postman.

I stay overnight for a few days. Please help me....

in my code

```
        let localUri = this.state.image; // <--- is image uri. 
        let filename = localUri.split('/').pop();


        let match = /\.(\w+)$/.exec(filename);
        let type = match ? `image/${match[1]}` : `image`;


        let formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('photo', { file: localUri, name: filename, type: type });

        return fetch(MY_SERVER, {
          method: 'POST',
          body: formData,
          headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          },
        }).then((response) => response.text())
              .then((responseData) => {
                  console.log(responseData);

                  console.log('file',formData)
              })
              .done();
```

in error messege
I don't think I can find the key called file.
Is this an API issue?

```
HTTP Status 400 – Bad Request
Required request part 'file' is not present
```

[image: POSTMAN]

[image: POSTMAN]

Answer (score 0):

I think the error resides in this line of code:

`formData.append('photo', { file: localUri, name: filename, type: type });`

Instead try to append like the following:

`formData.append('file', localUri);
 formData.append('name', filename);
 formData.append('type', type);`